# Filter, iterate, , cumsum, add to dataframe

Tags: pandas, loops, filter, group-by, cumsum

I have the following dataframe:

```
a,b,c,d
x,3,4,8
x,4,4,7
x,8,8,8
y,6,6,2
y,5,1,3
y,6,2,1
y,6,8,6
z,4,6,3
z,2,8,6
z,9,9,3
z,2,8,6
z,9,9,3
```

I’m looking to:

1. Filter for each value via (loop) in column a (x,y,z).
2. Then get the cumulative sum of the values in col b, for those filtered values (x being first)

So the cumulative sum of x, b would be:

```
3
7
15
```

3. Add that cumulative sum to another df, where I’ll do additional computation
4. Have the process repeat for the next value in col a, which is y. Which would be y, b:

```
6
11
17
23
```

5. Once all of x, y, and z have been processed, repeat for column c and d.

Currently I can do the proper loops, get the cumsum, and add to the other df using the code below.  The issue is that if in line 11 I try and have a variable (J) in the place of b which I need in order to iterate over columns b,c,d I get an error.

```
Input["WinStartTime"].unique()  
Starts = Input["WinStartTime"].unique().tolist() 
Cols = [b, b]

for I in Starts:
    InputLVPosU10 = (Input['WinStartTime'] == I) 

    for J in Cols:
        Input["Tot"] = Input[InputLVPosU10].b.cumsum()
        
        CS = pd.DataFrame(Input[InputLVPosU10].Tot) 
        print (CS)
        CS = CS.reset_index(drop=True)
```

error:

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
10 #         print(Input[InputLVPosU10].FinalinTicks.cumsum())
11
---> 12         Input["Tot"] = Input[InputLVPosU10].J.cumsum()  #Inject Tot column w running total of FinalinTicks-Filtered and then totaled...
13
14         CS = pd.DataFrame(Input[InputLVPosU10].Tot) #CS,New dataframe - Running total of everything in 'InputLVPosU10' Based on the Time

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **getattr**(self, name)
5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
5068
5069     def **setattr**(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'J'

---

I'm not sure if I have to use some other method, but any help would be great as I seem to have run into a dead end here...

Answer (score 0):

Avoid loops whenever you can in pandas and use the built-in functions:

```py
# The cumsum() will remove column a from the result set.
# So we need to assign it back
result = df.groupby("a").cumsum().assign(a=df["a"])

# Get the cumsum for x only
result[result["a"] == "x"]
```

Comment: Hello Code Different, 
Thank you for your feedback.  df.groupby("a").cumsum() does effectively get all the cumulative sum values in the, and removes the need to loop, which is great.
The .assign(a=df["a"]) seems to return the values of the initial column, without the sum, which I’m not clear on why.

Once I have the groupby cumsum column, how do I extract just the values of the cumsum of the first grouping of summations? For example the cumulative x values in column b?
3
7
15

Answer (score 0):

I think the previous answer is more of what you are looking for, but this is a simple SQL-esque way of getting there

```
from pandasql import sqldf
import pandas as pd
data = {'a':['x','x','x','y','y','y','y','z','z','z','z','z'],'b':[3,4,8,6,5,6,6,4,2,9,2,9],'c':[4,4,8,6,1,2,8,6,8,9,8,9],'d':[8,7,8,2,3,1,6,3,6,3,6,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
q = "select distinct a, sum(b) as b_sum, sum(c) as c_sum, sum(d) as d_sum from df group by a"
df_2 = sqldf(q,globals())
print(df_2)
   a  b_sum  c_sum  d_sum
0  x     15     16     23
1  y     23     17     12
2  z     26     40     21
```